# How to create new accented character in mathmode that works with superscripts and under scripts

Tags: macros, accents

I'm trying to write a macro that would yield in math mode the placement of a character (for example, `*`) above a variable (here, `x`) with superscripts (`^`) and underscripts (`_`) similar to what LaTeX does with `$\hat x_t^{ij}$` and `$\tilde x_t^{ij}$`.

I've tried  to set up in the preamble the following line (as per suggestions read here):

```
\newcommand{\st}[1]{\expandafter \overset{*}{#1}}
```

but the superscripts are aligned on top of the star unlike the tighter versions for `\tilde` and `\hat`.

Any suggestions?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`. You might also want to add to your question how you're including the pdfs etc.

Comment: I think you want to look at the `accents` package.

Comment: Will do next time. My apologies.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want the `accents` package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{accents}

\begin{document}

$\accentset{*}{x}_{t}^{ij}\ne x_{t}^{ij}$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Of course you can define a shorter macro for it:

```
\newcommand{\accs}[1]{\accentset{*}{#1}}
```

and then input the above formula as

```
$\accs{x}_{t}^{ij}\ne x_{t}^{ij}$
```